# Install and run a solr project in C9

Tags: laravel, solr, laravel-5, c9.io

Has anyone worked on installing solr on C9? I am currently have laravel on c9 but wasn't aware if solr can be installed in that environment. I am planning on laravel + solr in c9.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands to install solr

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
sudo pecl install -n solr
```

Then run

```
echo "extension=solr.so" >> /home/ubuntu/workspace/php.ini
```

to add it to your `php.ini` file. (Asuumming your `php.ini` file is located at `/home/ubuntu/workspace/php.ini`.)

Finally, run

```
sudo echo "extension=solr.so" > /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/solr.ini
```

To add it to your `solr.ini` file.